# L165 Power Op-amp LTspice model?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

Added:

I cleared my browser cache and the correct page popped up. Previously the link was just bringing me in a circle to the same LTspice group home page.

---

I am looking for an LTspice model of the L165.

Side note - in the LTspice groups.io (formerly yahoo) group page, I can't get these downloads to work:
[image]

I downloaded them, and opened them in edge, chrome and the web page https://groups.io/g/LTspice opened; no zip file or file directory etc. Is there a step or process I'm missing?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: VOTES TO CLOSE Would vote to closer's PLEASE provide indications why. The reasons given so far do not seem to suit.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The reason for the votes is "recommendation for products", but this question is anything but. I do think this should have been asked in the LTspice group since it relates to their Files/ section (therefore it's them who should be able to answer best). But then I see other questions on ee.se which can fall in the same category (e.g. similar to "why doesn't this do what I think it should?: type of questions). And the answers below have their merits.

Comment: @Mike Please advise whether the cache clear solved your problems or if you still have problems.  Any update useful

Comment: Yes cache clear solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There's enough information in [the L165 datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00000052.pdf) to use with LTspice's `UniversalOpamp2`.  This results in a decent model for most applications.

You can find `UniversalOpamp2` at the end of the `[Opamps]` folder when selecting a component symbol.  You can learn more about `UniversalOpamp2` in the included educational example (watch for typos!) found in `Documents\LTspiceXVII\examples\Educational\UniversalOpAmp.asc`

[image]

After you place the symbol, you can right-click it to access the parameters.  The main parameters to change are:

```
Avol
GBW
Slew
Ilimit
Rail
Vos
Rin
```

`Avol` is given in the datasheet's Electrical Characteristics as \$\text{G}_\text{v}\$, except it's in dB so it needs to be converted to V/V.  In this case, 80dB becomes 10k V/V.

`GBW` is tricky because it's indirectly given in Figure 4.  This figure shows the frequency response for a unity gain follower.  Therefore, the -3dB point on this curve is the gain bandwidth product (assuming single pole).  It's difficult to make out in this dilapidated figure (reproduced below), but I believe it's around 400k Hz.
[image]

`Slew` is also in the Electrical Characteristics (under \$\text{SR}\$), but it has different values for different gains.  I would choose the slower one, but you need to convert it from V/µs to V/s.  In other words, multiply it by `1e6` or `1meg`: 6 V/µs becomes 6meg V/s

`Ilimit` is directly found in the Absolute Maximum Ratings as \$\text{I}_\text{o}\$ with a value of 3.5A.

`Rail` is another one that doesn't match up directly.  The Electrical Characteristics section specifies it (under \$\text{V}_\text{o}\$) as the working peak-to-peak output range when including both rails.  LTspice wants it as the opposite, i.e. the magnitude from **each** rail it doesn't work (saturates).  Also, values at different frequencies and load currents are given, so I would pick the worst case scenario of 23 \$\text{V}_\text{pp}\$.  Since this is under the conditions of \$\text{V}_\text{s}=\$±15V, there is a total dead range of 30V - 23V = 7V.  Although the circuit topology of the output section found in the datasheet's "Schematic Diagram" looks asymmetrical, you can only specify a symmetrical range since `Rail` applies equally to both rails.  Therefore, selecting 7V / 2 = 3.5V would be the best we can use without resorting to bench testing the asymmetry of the output stage and adding external compensation voltage sources.

`Vos` is found directly in the Electrical Characteristics under \$\text{V}_\text{os}\$.  You can choose either the typical or maximum value, and the positive or negative version of it depending on your application.  I'll choose -2mV for now.  If this parameter is sensitive to your application, you can `.step param` this value across the entire -10mV to +10mV range to see how it affects your circuit.

`Rin` is found directly in the Electrical Characteristics under \$\text{R}\$.  They list both a minimum and typical value so choose what best suits your application.  I'll pick 500kΩ for now.

Aggregating the above...

```
Avol=10k
GBW=400k
Slew=6meg
Ilimit=3.5
Rail=3.5
Vos=-2m
Rin=500k
```

Finally, plugging in the values above should result in something that looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: People are voting to close this question as "Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic a ..." --> You spent a non minimal amount of time answering this. What do YOU think about the votes to close? (Your response may affect what happens subsequently).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon  I dunno.  The way I wrote the answer was such that it could be applied to all opamps.  Otherwise I wouldn't have wrote the answer.  As long as the information doesn't get deleted, I think it can still help others.

Comment: A limited number of people can see closed questions - and tose who need such answers most can't see them.

Answer (score 1):

They're index files, if what you want isn't in the index when you search it with a Ctrl-F or whatever then maybe it isn't there at all.

The only reference in messages that I see to the L165 is an offhand mention in a response to John Woodgate about 10 years ago, and nothing in files.

Maybe the TDA2030 model(s) are close enough for you. The L165 is obsolete anyway. So is the TDA2030, for that matter.

Comment: Thank you but when I save   all_files_z_yahoo.htm it saves as LTspice.htm. When I open LTspice.htm I just get https://groups.io/g/LTspice, no files.

Comment: I tried using the more modern OPA548 and LT1210. Regarding OPA548, it has enable and current limit pins and I could not find a suitable sym.

Comment: It's an html file so it should open with any browser, but  there's no point in saving it, just click on it and search it. OPAxx is a TI part so try them. Maybe you will have to use Tina.

Comment: Ok I cleared my browser cache and the correct page popped up. Previously the link was just bringing me in a circle to the same LTspice group home page.

Comment: People are voting to close this question as "Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic a ..." --> You spent a non minimal amount of time answering this. What do YOU think about the votes to close? (Your response may affect what happens subsequently).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I disagree. Some people probably don’t like the component ID questions either, which are similar. It’s not like there is a surfeit of high-quality questions. Note that there is no purchase taking place here that could contaminate the site with filthy lucre, the information on models is generally free.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'm trying to strike a balance between the democratic [tm] closing of questions by a smallish set of voters that people have spent good and useful effort on, and being seen as a tyrant overriding the will of the [limited subset of the] people.  I do not like the VTC reason given (but am aware that the choices are limited) and wish VTC people would improve the question and/or say why they are so voting. My tyrany stream may be growing stronger :-).