# Op-amp error calculation

Tags: operational-amplifier, spice, error

I am attempting to calculate the total error in an op-amp ([OPA2333](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2333-ht.pdf) to be specific) that is used in a voltage sensing circuit. If I use the OPA2333 model in my SPICE circuit, are the errors already accounted for when I run a sim? Or do I need to calculate the errors separately and model it into the circuit?

And by errors, I am referring to things like the following:

- Input offset voltage
- Input offset current
- CMRR
- PSRR
- Gain error

[image]

Comment: I can't say specifically for the OPA2333, but SPICE simulation usually has typical parameters, not worst case.

Comment: Please add the circuit you are referring to.

Comment: Just added a picture of the circuit. The output of this circuit is what goes into the ADC.

Comment: @flamezdude Do not forget the worst case for your resistor values. For example, [here I'm using a simple program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH1d7.png) I wrote that allows me to calculate any two remaining values, given others, and takes into account resistor tolerances. I just populated it with 10 k values and a few other details. Take a look at the report there at the bottom, showing the variation. This is just three resistors tied to a shared node.

Comment: @flamezdude Also watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdGqboW2VcY) which leads up to using Monte Carlo simulations in LTspice.

Comment: I uploaded my current version of the circuit that accounts for variations in resistor & power supply tolerances. It is still not clear to me what parameters, if any, in the op amps I should change to get worst case.

Comment: It's gonna be tricky without digging into the `OPAx333.LIB` file and reverse engineering how they came up with the model.  If you can evaluate the items in your list somewhat independently, you can run one simulation for CMRR + PSRR using TI's model.  Then you can do the other 3 errors using LTspice's `UniversalOpamp2` and mix your results together.  Vos (offset voltage) and Avol (gain error) are direct parameters, but you'll need to add current sources to model the offset/bias currents. See here:  https://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/build-an-op-amp-spice-model-from-its-datasheet-part-4/

Comment: See here how to map datasheet parameters to `UniversalOpamp2`: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/613637/254890

Answer (score 0):

You would need to compute worst case and specify the environmental range and R & IC component tolerances.  Then apply the worst case parameters for Vos, Ib, Ios, CMRR, PSSR, and apply the worst case resistor tolerances for the above along with cable impedance mismatch for CMRR and thus Vcm input then Vdm input and resulting SNR and gain error.

What are your expectations or requirements, acceptance critieria or **Specs**?