# AD8051 op-amp strange output in TINA-TI as a voltage follower with input < 0.4V

Tags: operational-amplifier, tina

I need to simulate the [AD8051](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8051_8052_8054.pdf) op-amp in TINA-TI. I have no other choice; it has to be TINA TI. I imported the spice model [from here](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad8051.html) using the new macro wizard like shown:

[image]

When simulating as a voltage follower, I get the "correct" voltage at the output for 1 V, 0.9 V, 0.8 V, etc. but right around 0.3 V it breaks and I get about 509 mV. So 300 mV input, 509 mV output. What could be going on here?

Interestingly, I do not get this outcome in LTspice. Is TINA broken, or is there some specification in the datasheet that would explain this?

[image]

**Update:**

As suggested, I have imported the macro model such that the pins on the symbol match the pins in the datasheet. I used this diagram, since it is an AD8051 model:

[image]

I also used a generic header symbol to make this a little easier to read. In any case, I have the same result despite the 5 pins lining up correctly. My next step will be to reach out to analog devices. I'll update again when they give me an answer. I am still leaning towards this being related to there being no load attached.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you did anything wrong.  Something is wrong with TINA's results for some reason.  I built the macro the same way as you and get the same results.  However, if I export the resultant netlist and run it in LTspice or ngspice I get `0.301879V` at the opamp output (without a load) in both simulators.  Anyway, this shows that for the same netlist, TINA produces different results.  I know you said you have to use TINA, but something is definitely wrong and I don't know if it's worth trying to troubleshoot it.  There's a reason why most people use LTspice, ngspice, or Micro-Cap...

Comment: Yes i’ve been told to stay away from TINA. TI’s encrypted model files which only work in TINA are what make it mandatory. I could just simulate it in LTSpice, then use a voltage source to represent the amplifier. If you just use a generic ideal op amp you will get the same problem with TINA. I would love to reach out to TI but it doesn’t look like you can use their forums without an employee account.

Comment: I did more experiments which narrow down the weird behavior.  I'll try to post an official answer later to document my findings.  You should be able to use the [TI support forums](https://e2e.ti.com/) with a standard free user account.  I'm curious to know which part number is encrypted...can you share the part#?  One alternative approach is to use LTspice's `UniversalOpamp2` to make your own approximation to the amplifier you need.  Here is an example I laid out previously: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/613637

Comment: @ste kulov Yes please share your answer. This is quite a mystery. AMC1100 has an encrypted SPICE model from TI.

Comment: Here's a rough model I made for the AMC1100 in LTspice, all based on info found in the datasheet.  Everything within the dotted box is the IC itself.  I tried copying info from the TINA-TI Reference Design for the other external components.  The model assumes VDD1 and VDD2 are both 5V.  If VDD2 is 3V or 3.3V, then V5 needs to change to 1.29V according to the datasheet.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q6TB.png