# Singular Matrix error

Tags: circuit-design, ltspice

Thanks for taking the time to response.

I am getting a singular matrix error, in my circuit design.

It happens when I connect Q4 to the output of U5 LM358, so I think it has have something to do with Q4 (in yellow). I using it to go high to pull down the output of U5.

Do you have any suggests on how to fix this error?
[image]

This is the full circuit:
[image]
[image]
The output at R8:
[image]

Comment: Which node is U3:6, as complained about in the error message?

Comment: You can search for a node with ctrl+F

Comment: I believe it is the op amps from U3 to U6.

Comment: I believe it is the op amps from U3 to U6. However, when i change Q4 to different NPN it changes where the singular matrix error occurs. For example I change it to BC847B and it work for the first 7seconds, and then got a singular matrix error, so i think it is something to do with Q4, and when i removed Q4 it gets no error.

Comment: When Q4 is fully turned on, it'll short-circuit the output of U5 (LM358) to GND. Is this what you want? (BTW, U3 is the yellow component, not Q4 like stated in your question.)

Comment: Rolled back your replacement picture, as you **removed the relevant error message**. That's counterproductive, because the error message tells you where the problem is. It's in one of the nodes of U3, which you don't show; your new picture had different component labels, so the error message would probably be different. If you decide to replace the image with your newer screenshot (please do!) also add, in **verbatim** the error message as you got it.

Comment: Sorry for removing the original image.  I just used the new images to show the circuit. The components are label the same and the error consists. Yes, i do want to short-circuit. the idea is to make the system turn off if the current is to high

Comment: What happens if you put a 10 ohm resistor in the collector of Q4?  Also, where did you get your LM358 model from?

Comment: the resistor there does help a lot, but 15 seconds into the simulation it gets the same error. Also, if i remember correctly i got it from spice file from ti.

Comment: What happens if you replace all your LM358s with `UniversalOpamp2` found in the built-in LTspice opamp folder (scroll to the end)?  Many TI subcircuits don't run well in LTspice...so it's worth seeing what happens when using `UniversalOpamp2` which is very efficient.  Then you know if the issue is with your circuit or the simulation model from TI.  Keep in mind that using this type of "shorting the output to ground" method of "turning off" the system is very poor and prone to damaging the opamp.  See Note 6 under the Absolute Maximum Ratings chart in the datasheet.

Comment: Thanks that works. using opamp2. Do you have any suggests on how to make a lm358 work in it?

Comment: Tweaking TI's problematic models until they work is not worth the effort.  Instead, you can try changing the parameters of `UniversalOpamp2` to match the LM358, similar to what I did [here in this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/613637).  Otherwise, I would try one of the two non-TI models found within [Bordodynov's "additional library" package](http://bordodynov.ltwiki.org/).  The one called `LM358As.SUB` is basically using `UniversalOpamp2` anyway.  The other one called `LM358_AB.sub` looks to be a transistor-based model.